# angular change detection in interaction test

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I have a simple reactive form (angular 11)

```html
<form class="searchForm" [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="firstName" required/>
  <button [disabled]="! form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-form',
  templateUrl: './my-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-form.component.css']
})
export class MyFormComponent {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl()
    });
  }
}
```

I am trying to do a simple interaction test, I am setting a value
in the required text field, the triggering an input event. I am expecting
that after the event angular runs change detection and would update the
disabled state of the button, but this does not happen. I have to trigger
change detection manually to have the button have the correct disabled state.
I am slightly puzzled about this behaviour.

```js
 it('should enable submit button', () => {

    const input: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('input[formControlName="firstName"]');
    const button: HTMLButtonElement = document.querySelector('button');

    // simulate user interaction
    input.focus();
    input.value = 'john';

    expect(component.form.valid).toBeFalse();
    expect(button.disabled).toBeTruthy();

    const event = new Event('input', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    });
    input.dispatchEvent(event);

    // required field has text -> form valid
    expect(component.form.valid).toBeTrue();

    // but button is still disabled
    expect(button.disabled).toBeTrue();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    // only after detectChanges the disabled state is correct
    expect(button.disabled).toBeFalse();

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default, you have to manually call change detection in Angular spec tests.** This is explained in the [Angular docs "Component testing scenarios"](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#createcomponent-does-not-bind-data).

> In production, change detection kicks in automatically when Angular creates a component or the user enters a keystroke or an asynchronous activity (e.g., AJAX) completes.

> Delayed change detection [in tests] is intentional and useful. It gives the tester an opportunity to inspect and change the state of the component before Angular initiates data binding and calls lifecycle hooks.

**You can enable automatic change detection in Angular spec tests.**
This can be useful if you don't want to deal with manually calling change detection (either because you need to call it a lot or don't feel it's useful for your scenario). It's possible to enable automatic change detection **by configuring the TestBed with the ComponentFixtureAutoDetect provider.**

i.e.,

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyFormComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
  ]
});
```

However, be aware there are some limits to using this provider.

> The ComponentFixtureAutoDetect service responds to asynchronous activities such as promise resolution, timers, and DOM events.

So this should work in your case because you are performing a DOM interaction via the `input.dispatchEvent()` call. However, if you want to directly update a component without DOM interaction, you need to call `detectChanges()`.

> But a direct, synchronous update of the component property is invisible. The test must call fixture.detectChanges() manually to trigger another cycle of change detection.

i.e.,

```
it('should display updated title after detectChanges', () => {
  comp.title = 'Test Title';
  fixture.detectChanges(); // detect changes explicitly to see direct component update.
  expect(h1.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
});
```

See [Automatic change detection in Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#automatic-change-detection) for more info.